# Is there a legend some place that describes all of these color-coded values at the bottom of byobu?

Tags: terminal, byobu

On my EC2 instance I am presented with a screen where the bottom looks like

[image]

Some of the values seem pretty clear to me.

Is there a legend available, or some place that explains this various color coded regions for byobu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a few samples from the [**byobu** documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/byobu), section ***Status Notifications***:

> **cpu_count** - the number of cpu's or cores on the  system;  displayed  in the lower bar toward the right in the default text color
>   on the default background, followed by a trailing 'x'
>
> **cpu_freq** - the current frequency of the cpu in GHz;  displayed  in  the lower bar toward the right in white text on a light blue
>   background
>
> **disk_io**  -  instantaneous read/write througput in kB/s or MB/s over the last 3 seconds; displayed in the lower bar toward the  right 
>   in  white text  on  a  light purple background with a leading '<' sign
>   indicating 'read speed' and  '>'  sign  indicating  'write  speed'; 
>   override  the default   monitored   disk  by  specifying  an 
>   alternate  device  with MONITORED_DISK=/dev/sdb, and override the
>   default  DISK_IO_THRESHOLD=50 (kB/s) in $BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR/statusrc

By [default](http://www.naturalborncoder.com/linux/2014/10/28/getting-started-with-byobu/):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As the maintainer of Byobu and the author of the documentation quoted above, I would VERY much prefer if StackExchange LINKED to the manpage, rather than snapshotting and duplicating it here.  I have licensed the documentation you quote above with the GPLv3, and NOT the CC-WIKI license that StackExchange operates under.

Comment: @DustinKirkland Technically it did both, which seems ideal -- we encourage users to not [just link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) to other pages in their answers, in case those pages go down and the answer becomes useless. In any case, I removed the duplicated text

Comment: That kinda works, but your man page will 404 eventually. Links are not future proof. It is necessary to snapshot bits and pieces. I can see your point that I snapshotted too much, but Michael's edit took out WAY too much.

Comment: The better link to use, from my perspective, is http://manpg.es/byobu.1, which is a shortened url and always will point to the latest version.

Comment: @hamlin11, your answer is a good one, and I +1'd it.  I'm sorry if my comment came down too hard, but I really hope to avoid duplicating the content of manpages in StackExchange.  I am asking more and more Byobu user to ask their questions here.  But so many of them are clearly answered in the manpages :-(

Comment: #DustinKirkland, I'm afraid your rights are removed for it's academic use here. That does mean it isn't allowed to reproduce more of it than required. It also doesn't allow StackExchange to claim rights of reproduction, which is a significant problem. I'd recommend you to sue StackExchange and have them solve this fundamental problem that encourages copyright infrigment and threatens technical writer's rights all across the world.

Comment: @Lodewijk First, calm down about legal action. Second, do a bit of research on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use . This is clearly a snippet for research and teaching purposes. Not only that, it leads off with a link to the author's main source. The snippet is only provided in case the destination 404's.

Comment: I wrote "I'm afraid your rights are removed for it's academic use here.". The legal problem is that stackexchange claims answers are under CC-WIKI, users might then blame StackExchange for claiming a certain license, and StackExchange can blame "safe harbor" rights.
This construction causes an unclarity of responsibility on top of an unmanageable rights crisis. Only a lawsuit will determine who is right, as it is too vague to determine otherwise. The precedent will be valuable insight for all similar cases that follow. It is not an adversarial lawsuit.

Comment: Still, 32 is way too much (hence the exclamation mark) ;p

Answer (score 0):

Since these byobu status line fields can be easily customized by pressing `F9`, then selecting `Toggle status notifications`, or customized by your OS instance, any legend you find may not match your installation. To list the status names of your particular status line, you can search your own byobu config file to list the keywords.

The examples below assume that your byobu configuration is located in `~/.byobu/`, but it may be elsewhere.

Find out whether your byobu is using screen or tmux:

```
$ cat ~/.byobu/backend
BYOBU_BACKEND=tmux
```

Then look for the corresponding status line setting in `~/.byobu/status` and omit the disabled keywords, which start with `#`:

For a **tmux** backend:

```
$ grep ^tmux_ ~/.byobu/status | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v '^#'
```

For a **screen** backend:

```
$ grep ^screen_ ~/.byobu/status | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v '^#'
```

Using `tr` to replace spaces with newlines makes it easier to read. So does using `grep` to omit the unused keywords.

I created an alias so I can easily view my status line legend:

```
$ alias byobustat="grep ^tmux_ ~/.byobu/status | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v '^#'"
$ byobustat 
tmux_left="
logo
release
session"
tmux_right="
network
disk_io
custom
raid
reboot_required
updates_available
users
uptime
cpu_temp
processes
load_average
cpu_count
cpu_freq
memory
swap
disk
hostname
time_utc
date
time"
```